# Using a Word document as a template for an SSRS report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, reporting-services, ms-word

Greetings.

I've got a few Word documents that I need to send as notifications when something happens.  I've got to fill 10 parameters or so from our SQL Server database.  Note that I don't need to send them as word documents, PDF will be fine - I was just given them in .docx form.

Now, I immediately thought SSRS was the way to go here.  Now that I've spent some time with the Textbox control and it's lack of formatting (SQL2005), I'm not so sure.

Anyone have an idea for a better way to go about this?  Right now I'm using TONS of textboxes as I've got to have certain things underlined, certain things bolded, plus all of the parameters that need to be filled.

There's got to be a better solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is Reporting Services the right tool for this job? You could easily automate Word 2007 using [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=F5539A90-DC41-4792-8EF8-F4DE62FF1E81&displaylang=en), do a merge with your data and mail out the actual documents or a PDF of them.